# Why visual studio doesn't come with Resources template by default?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

Hello I am trying to create a “.resx” file and when I went to the menu add “new item” it doesn't show me the template for create resources file as it shows in the following image. But if I go to Visual Studio 2015 it actually shows that option available. So why if it is visual studio 2017 it doesn't come with that template by default ? And I want to know what are the steps that I have to take in order to install this template.

Note: **If my question is incorrectly please AND YOU ARE GOING TO GIVE ME A DISLIKE  make sure to GIVE ME A FEEDBACK** Thank you for reading this.

[click here to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmf5G.png)

Comment: Works just fine.  It is normally displayed underneath "General".  You ought to be concerned about the wind damage that "Storm" might have done, clearly it should not be omitted from the question.  Get ahead by spinning the repair/reinstall wheel of fortune.

Comment: At least in my visual studio installation there is no repair and reinstall. Anyways I can create manually a resource file but it would not generate any code for the designer.cs if you know what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

After having the same issue (I think). I found that you have to choose ".NET desktop develpment" when you install VS 2017 to get the resource template.

Search for visual studio installer in your menu and then choose modify.
Check ".NET desktop develpment" and click modify. After that you should be able to see the templates in VS 2017.
[image]

Comment: I faced exact same problem in VS 2019 and the response from @Fred solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

what about this one?

[ResX Manager](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TomEnglert.ResXManager)

Comment: Well is not yet resolve this situation I guess I have to reinstall.